# Booting Ubuntu on an UEFI system with Windows 8

Tags: 12.04, uefi, windows-8

I have a preview Windows 8 from a friend and right now I am downloading the ISO from 12.04 Alpha. I want to know if I will be able to boot Ubuntu from the same PC that has Windows 8 taking into consideration that the motherboard has UEFI. I ask because of the whole Windows 8 blocking other OS's issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/94165/can-i-keep-burg-on-a-triple-boot-with-windows-7-and-windows-8/94732#94732

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not Windows 8 that locks down the bootloader, it is the BIOS. Windows cannot stop a program from writing to the MBR if it is turned off. The BIOS can, however, refuse to boot if the hash of the boot sector is not what it is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this situation is to disable UEFI, or, if your setup is similar to mine, it can handle UEFI+Legacy booting... Suffice it to say, I disabled UEFI immediately.

If you're the technogeek kind, and say, want to run a hackintosh setup, you can kiss it goodbye with UEFI.

It's just a method of locking your computer down from yourself, call it a corporate, closed source control mechanism, because if you're smart, you don't get boot-time viruses in the first place.