# I cannot install Ubuntu on my laptop running Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 (ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso) to my 4GB USB Sandisk drive so that I could install it on my laptop. I was able to get to the setup but when I would get to the part where it would ask me if I want to replace Windows or install next to it I chose to install next to it and then it would restart the computer. I wanted to try using Wubi.exe to install it from Windows but I'm afraid to do that since all it says for destination is C: which is the place I use for Windows 8. I can run Ubuntu off the USB stick but I'd like to install it next to Windows 8 so that I can dual-boot between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 introduce two features :

- UEFI witch is instead of BIOS
- Secure Boot witch prevent anything but the installed operating system (here it's windows) to boot

The procedure is quite complex. Look at this question for further information :
[How to install Ubuntu on UEFI enabled HP Pavilion HPE h9 tower](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130392/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-uefi-enabled-hp-pavilion-hpe-h9-tower)

Comment: But my laptop came originally came with Windows 7 and all I did was upgraded?

My laptop was bought in 2010. It's an HP-g62.

Comment: Your laptop has UEFI. try this : http://www.intowindows.com/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu/